# How do I render a nested object's property inside an array inside another array in MuiDatatables?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mui-datatable, nested-object

```
data: [{
       0: {
          item: {
              attributes: [
                  {0},
                  {1},
                   2: 
                       id: 1,
                       key:"Some String",
                       value: "23423"
            ]
        }  
    }
}]
```

```
    {
            label: 'effectiveFrom',
            name: 'item.effectiveFrom',
            options: {
              filter: true,
              sort: true
            },
          },
          {
            label: 'Vendors',
            name: 'item.attributes[2].value',
            options: {
              filter: true,
              sort: true
            },
          }
```

above is the columns and their options using MuiDatatables, I thought using `item.attributes[2].value` would output the string but it doesn't

If anyone can help, that would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work?

```
{
  label: 'Vendors',
  name: 'item',
  options: {
    filter: true,
    sort: true,
    customBodyRender: (item, meta) => (<>${item.attributes[2].value}</>),
  },
}
```

But I think that MuiDataTables might have a soft requirement on the data already being flattened.

From the docs:

> Data used to describe table. Must be either an array containing objects of key/value pairs with values that are strings or numbers, or arrays of strings or numbers (Ex: data: [{"Name": "Joe", "Job Title": "Plumber", "Age": 30}, {"Name": "Jane", "Job Title": "Electrician", "Age": 45}] or data: [["Joe", "Plumber", 30], ["Jane", "Electrician", 45]]) Use of arbitrary objects as data is not supported, and is deprecated. Consider using ids and mapping to external object data in custom renderers instead e.g. const data = [{"Name": "Joe", "ObjectData": 123}] --> const dataToMapInCustomRender = { 123: { foo: 'bar', baz: 'qux', ... } }

You could always transform it yourself before passing it to the table.

Answer (score 0):

What actually worked was, selecting the object based on the key, and then returning the value associated with that key

```
    {
                label: 'Vendors',
                name: 'item.attributes',
                options: {
                  filter: true,
                  sort: true,
                  customBodyRender: (value: any) => {
            return value.map( (val: any, key: any ) => {
              if(val.key === "Some String") {
                return <Chip label={val.value} key={key}/>;
              }
            })
          }
                },
              }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `enableNestedDataAccess: '.'` in options object, This allows for nested data separated by a “.”